# Synchronizing Two Arrays of Points

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays of points of the format {Time,Y Value}, for example:

```
A - [{1,1} {2, 2} {3, 3} {5, 5}]

B - [{1,1} {4, 4} {5, 5}]
```

I need both arrays to have the same time discretization.  So for every point with time t in A, there needs to be a point in B with the same time, and vice versa.  If it doesn't exist in the array, a new point should be added with Y value equal to the previous point.

So after synchronizing A and B, they should look like:

```
A - [{1,1} {2, 2} {3, 3} {4, 3} {5, 5}]

B - [{1,1} {2, 1} {3, 1} {4, 4} {5, 5}]
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this for large arrays?

Comment: To be clear, the arrays are sorted? Also, does the solution *have* to be array based (e.g. `List`s may be a better data structure to work with here)

Comment: How about sorting the arrays by time, then iterating with two indexes, one for each array, starting both at 0, at each iteration if the times are equal, increment both indexes, if one is smaller add the appropriate value to that array and only increment that index.

Comment: Smells like homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the max array size and the time will always be a multiple of 1 as shown in your example, you could use two arrays that large of nullable `int`s (`int?`) where all values start as null, then set them to integer values based on however you load the initial arrays.  Then you don't have to do anything ugly like search through lists of different lengths, growing the list every time you need to insert a value, etc.--it's all done by array index.  If you then need the lists in more compact form, you can zip through the arrays and add all non-null items to the list as coordinate pairs like what you've shown.

I suppose if you don't know the max time value, you could use a `List<int?>` instead of an `int?[]`; you'd just need to make sure every time value is represented (meaning there's a `null` for every time value not in the list).  The key is being able to map from time value to list index so there's no searching involved.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code assuming `A` and `B` are sorted by time:

```
Sync(A, B)
    def indA = 0
    def indB = 0
    while indA < length(A) and indB < length(B)
        if A[indA].time == B[indB].time
             indA++
             indB++
        else if A[indA].time < B[indB].time
             insert {time: B[indB].time, value: A[indA].value} to A at indA+1
             indA++
        else
             insert {time: A[indA].time, value: B[indB].value} to B after indB+1
             indB++
```